# Route not found in react-router-native when using eslint

Tags: react-native, react-router, eslint

I have the following in my js file:

```
import { NativeRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-native'
```

When running eslint I get the following error:

```
error  Route not found in 'react-router-native'  import/named
```

However my application runs perfectly fine, I just get the error when I'm running eslint. Why is this?

From package.json:

```
"eslint": "^4.15.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
"eslint-config-react-native": "^2.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.2.1",


"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like eslint is reporting correctly. I no longer get an error after changing my js to:

```
import { NativeRouter, Link } from 'react-router-native'
import { Route } from 'react-router'
```

The rule says that all named imports must be part of the set of named exports: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/named.md

`react-router-native` is re-exporting `Route` from `react-router`, but it isn't named when re-exported from 
`react-router-native`. At least that's my understanding.